# Is talaq complete when they can both agree to get back together before three months?

Tags: sharia, talaq

My uncle secretly married someone then divorced her after we caught him.  All matters aside, importantly their contract says he/she can come back to her at any time if they both agree again and this is up to 3 months only, if 3 months have expired they cannot come back together without a new contract. My question is: is this complete talaq? Why did he not divorce her completely?

Is my uncle trying to fool us again and marry her again?

I am just curious. I don't want to ask my uncle (I have social anxiety).  Please enlighten me. I am not an expert at this stuff, so please be very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

In fact **this is proper way of talaq**, the way of talaq which we use now a days, giving all 3 talaqs at once or with little breaks is not SUNNAH. And sunnah is against this practice. **It is the need of hour to revive sunnah way of talaaq, which we were taught originally.**

> “**Divorce according to Sunnah** is that the woman is divorced in a state
>   of cleanliness (Tohr) without an intercourse, the **husband gives one
>   divorces and leaves her as such till the iddat is over**.”
>   (Mugni-ibneQuddamah Vol 7P. 98)
>
> “**The best procedure for divorce** is that the husband should give one
>   divorce to his wife, and that too when she is in a state of
>   cleanliness and he had not had an intercourse with her. Then he should
>   lea ye her in the same state till the term of iddat is over. This
>   procedure is better, **because the Companions of the Prophet (R) desired
>   that more than one divorce should not be given till the period of
>   iddat is over.**” (Hidayah- Vol. 1 Page 179)
>
> Rasulullah (SAW) was informed about **a man who had divorced his wife
>   with all the three pronunciations, so
>   he(prophet S.A.W.W) stood up angrily and said: "Is the book of Allah played around with
>   while I am still in your midst?**"...until a man got up (with his
>   unsheathed sword) and said: O Rasulullah, shall I not kill him?
>
> [an-Nasai]

*(Although this hadees is about giving 3 talaaqs in one sitting, still it is relevant. And other two references are from two of the most acknowledged books of fiqh.)*

**One talaq is enough to break the legal binding of the husband and wife(after iddah period). And this is a preferable way, their are many hidden benefits if one follows this.** One is that if someone divorces his wife in anger on some fake accusation, there's no way back after 3 talaqs, purpose of islam is not to separate people but to keep them unite. So, if one talaq is given, which is proper and valid way of talaq, than a person can make RUJU or re-marry if differences are resolved and accusations are proved wrong. This is one of the reasons why this is a prefered way. 3 talaqs are intended to be used for 3 separate nikahs, one talaq is enough to cancel one nika, second talq should be used on second nikah. Read [more here](http://www.islamawareness.net/Talaq/talaq_book.html).

### About pressurizing for talaq

**Having said that, i should also mention that IF your uncle gave this talaq on someone's pressure, than God forbid, the person who pressurized for this is in deep trouble.** Talaaq is a huge thing, and is only ALLOWED to avoid more harm. If someone pressurized someone to give talaaq to his wife, he should repent to Allah.

> **“To Allah the most undesirable thing among the lawful things is
>   divorce.”** (Abu Dawood)

And think about if someone is forcing this most undesirable thing when it could had been avoided without his/her pressure. May Allah forgive us all.

> The Prophet (peace_be_upon_him) said: **Anyone who
>   incites a woman against her husband or a slave against his master is
>   not one of us**.

Also we all know about this hadees:

> Jabir reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon
>   him, said, **“Verily, Satan places his throne over the water and he
>   sends out his troops. The closest to him in rank are the greatest at
>   causing tribulations. One of them says: I have done this and this.
>   Satan says: You have done nothing. Another one says: I did not leave
>   this man alone until I separated him from his wife. Satan embraces him
>   and he says: You have done well.”**
>
> Source: Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 2813

The purpose of mentioning all above against divorce is to make it clear how bad it is considered to give divorce. A man has right to marry on his own, Allah has given this right to him, no one should take this right from him.

### Allah knows best

Comment: What if my uncle was cheating on his older wife and mistreating her? and she said either pick me or her? is that pressure?

Comment: @OkamaKsakas Brother, this is pressure. And i think this is a spearate question, that will be good if you post this matter of pressure by first wife in a separate question. Jazakallah. You can give its link here so we can answer it if we can :)